# WebDriverManager integration with jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, webdriver-manager, webdrivermanager-java

I am having issues in running WebDriverManager in Jenkins
this is my code:

```
                WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
                FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = (FirefoxOptions) options;
                return new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
```

locally it works perfectly but on jenkins I am getting this error:

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed. OS appears to be: LINUX

Any idea what can I do in order to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Install Firefox on Jenkins. If it is a headless environment, you will also need to install Xvfb (X virtual framebuffer) and set a `DISPLAY` environmental variable. More info for instance [here](https://www.coveros.com/run-headless-selenium-tests-from-jenkins/).